# Data Source for tableview in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

What is the better data model for a `tableview`?  `NSArray` of dictionary for example or is it better do a `NsArray` of a personal data class?

Answer (score 0):

I think in general (whether you're designing a data source for a table view or any other data model) it's better to be specific than using general purpose classes like Dictionary. It may give you some additional flexibility if you need to be dynamic, but most of the time designing a special class provides semantic meaning for the data that would otherwise be lost (e.g. what is a key ? what is a value ?)

Answer (score 0):

Whichever suits you best. There's no real recommendation to make, other than to use what's most "natural" to your application. For example, if you already have some custom class and want to represent its data in a tableview, then of course you should simply use your custom class and not try to cram it into a dictionary. If on the other hand you have some data that doesn't need a dedicated class (for example because it's just a group of text data that doesn't need to be manipulated) then a dictionary might be way to go.